# Drupal content to sharepoint

Tags: wiki, wiki-pages

Im currently investigating if I can move drupal page content ( simple text articles) into Sharepoint wiki pages. I have zero Sharepoint experience at this point.

My previous searches were not very promising in finding something resembling a plugin that given documents it will automatically create wiki pages. Do you know of anything like that?

If not, can I do it with a script calling some API? What are my options here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal is all PHP and MySql

So you can push content from the PHP side to SharePoint with the connector
Vadim Gremyachev created: https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

But... If you don't have SharePoint experience, you have a learning path first